# EJB @DependsOn along with CDI Instance not working

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

i have a bean which is annotated like this:

```
@Stateless
@DependsOn("Bar")
public class Foo implements Inf {}
```

and a bean called "Bar" like this:

```
@Stateless
public class Bar implements Inf {}
```

and i collect every bean via:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Boo {

@Inject
Instance<Inf> infs; 

}
```

This works fine. However, it seems that @DependsOn does not work properly. Everytime i startup my container the class "Foo" will be executed before "Bar" ..

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you say  class `Foo` will be executed before `Bar` ??  please add some error stacktrace or proof to that Thank You. @Christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DependsOn is only valid for singletons, it makes no sense in the context of stateless beans

Comment: ahh i see! Thanks for claryfing. But is there a way to have a "dependency" to another bean which is not marked as @Singleton? Actually i dont want that bean forever in the heap

Comment: You can inject beans into eachother with \@EJB <YourBean> or if you are using CDI then \@Inject. CDI also allows you to have smaller scopes than \@Singleton such as \@RequestScoped or your custom defined scope. \@stateless beans by definition though do not hold state so you should only rely on functionality not actual held data